# What is the best practice to store state variables in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm new to Java.
Say I want to make a simple game with Swing or whatever. How and where do I store variables like the player's score or progress, for example, so that I can access it from different classes (during the game and before persistence in the database). I like how we use useContext in React. I also used global variables in PHP's sessions.

Comment: I highly advice to not use a "global state". I would rather recommend to implement a domain object or service that fetches high scores. This service can then be injected and called where needed.

Comment: What I know to do is this  ... Service service = new Service (); service.setScore(score), but this object is local to the object where it is instantiated and not shared with other classes.

Comment: Given the fact that you are talking about a "simple" game, and probably don't want to go overboard ... the *somehow hackish* answer: use a singleton. For example an **enum** that has a single instance that provides you with that Service object. Or doe old school way of having a `public static Service getService()` method somewhere. Then all your code that needs the service can pull it from there (instead of thinking about Dependency Injection frameworks that provide it to your objects).

Comment: Take a look at the [model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern.  For a simple game, you create a game model to hold state.  High scores could be kept in the main model, or in individual `Player` class instances.

Answer (score 3):

I highly advice to not use a "global state". I would rather recommend to implement a domain object or service that fetches high scores. This service can then be injected and called where needed.

Using a domain object or a service to access and modify domain data has the benefit that ownership is clearly defined: the business object/service owns the data, and the data is only accessed and modified through the business object/service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I don't know how to implement what you suggest, added to that I don't understand it completely. I wish I know some book or tutorial that teaches me this particular point in a focused manner.